# How to change the Symlink permission?

Tags: permissions, symlink

I have a issue: I need to change the permission of the symlink from     777 to 755 and I do not have any idea how should I do it. I have tried using the `chmod` command but it's not working.
I want

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 frosu  2016_cluj     5 Jul  4 13:53 test6 -> test0
```

to

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 frosu  2016_cluj     5 Jul  4 13:53 test6 -> test0
```

Comment: Se my reply below: The permissions of symlinks are usually not evaluated. Whether or not you are able to change this bits depends on whether your OS supports POSIX.1-2008

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some systems support changing the permission of a symbolic link, others do not.

- [chmod -- change file modes or Access Control Lists](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) (OSX and [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?chmod), using `-h`)

  > **`-h`**      If the file is a symbolic link, change the mode of the link itself rather than the file that
  >            the link points to.
- [chmod - change file mode bits](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) (Linux)

  > **`chmod`** never changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod
  >   system call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem
  >      since the permissions of symbolic links are never used.  However, for
  >      each symbolic link listed on the command line, chmod changes the
  >      permissions of the pointed-to file.  In contrast, chmod ignores
  >      symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals.

Since the feature differs, [**POSIX**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) does not mention the possibility.

From comments, someone suggests that a recent change to GNU coreutils provides the `-h` option.  At the moment, that does not appear in the [source-code for chmod](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/chmod.c#n434):

```
  while ((c = getopt_long (argc, argv,
                           ("Rcfvr::w::x::X::s::t::u::g::o::a::,::+::=::"
                            "0::1::2::3::4::5::6::7::"),
                           long_options, NULL))
```

and [`long_options`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/chmod.c#n94) has this:

```
static struct option const long_options[] =
{
  {"changes", no_argument, NULL, 'c'},
  {"recursive", no_argument, NULL, 'R'},
  {"no-preserve-root", no_argument, NULL, NO_PRESERVE_ROOT},
  {"preserve-root", no_argument, NULL, PRESERVE_ROOT},
  {"quiet", no_argument, NULL, 'f'},
  {"reference", required_argument, NULL, REFERENCE_FILE_OPTION},
  {"silent", no_argument, NULL, 'f'},
  {"verbose", no_argument, NULL, 'v'},
  {GETOPT_HELP_OPTION_DECL},
  {GETOPT_VERSION_OPTION_DECL},
  {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};
```

Permissions are set with **`chmod`**.  Ownership is set with **`chown`**.  GNU coreutils (like BSD) supports the ability to change a symbolic link's ownership.  This is a different feature, since the ownership of a symbolic link is related to whether one can modify the contents of the link (and point it to a different target).  Again, this started as a BSD feature (OSX, [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chown&sektion=8), etc), which is also supported with [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html) (and [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/chown-1.html), etc).  [POSIX says of *this* feature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html):

> **`-h`**
>       For each file operand that names a file of type symbolic link, chown shall attempt to set the user ID of the symbolic link. If a group ID was specified, for each file operand that names a file of type symbolic link, chown shall attempt to set the group ID of the symbolic link.

So much for the command-line tools (and shell scripts). However, you could *write* your own utility, using a [feature of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) which is not mentioned in the discussion of the `chmod` utility:

> `int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);`
>   `int fchmodat(int fd, const char *path, mode_t mode, int flag);`

The latter function adds a *flag* parameter, which is described thus:

> Values for *flag* are constructed by a bitwise-inclusive OR of flags from the following list, defined in `<fcntl.h>`:
>
> **`AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW`**
>   If *path* names a symbolic link, then the mode of the symbolic link is changed.

That is, the purpose of `fchmodat` is to provide the feature you asked about.  But the command-line `chmod` utility is documented (so far) only in terms of `chmod` (without this feature).

`fchmodat`, by the way, appears to have started as a poorly-documented feature of Solaris which was adopted by the Red Hat and GNU developers ten years ago, and suggested by them for standardization:

- [one more openat-style function required: fchmodat](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2006-01/msg00024.html)
- [Austin Group Minutes of the 17 May 2007  Teleconference](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/docs/austin_364.txt)
- [[Fwd: The Austin Group announces Revision Draft 2 now available]](https://lwn.net/Articles/207927/)

According to [*The Linux Programming Interface*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2SAQAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA365&lpg=PA365&dq=linux%20%22AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW%22&source=bl&ots=qQv4bcABtw&sig=yxaNBtzcsvOPAuHGa77u5sIr5VM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI3bndqtrNAhUDWz4KHYwEDmQQ6AEIWjAJ#v=onepage&q=linux%20%22AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW%22&f=false), since 2.6.16, Linux supports `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` in these calls: [`faccessat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html), `fchownat`, `fstatat`, [`utimensat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html), and `linkat` was implemented in 2.6.18 (both rather "old": [2006, according to OSNews](http://www.osnews.com/story/15902/Linux-Kernel-2.6.18-Released/)).

Whether the feature is useful to you, or not, depends on the systems that you are using.

Comment: My man page says AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW is not currently implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The permission for symlinks is not evaluated.

In former times, there was no way to change the permission bits for symlinks.

Since a while, POSIX introduced `fchmodat()` and all platforms that support this call, are able to change the permission bits for symlinks.

Do not expect this to have effects on the symlink though.